# Finding a string in XML column using sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

1. I have a table with a xml column.
2. I require to search for sub string in that xml column for all its node and value. Search should be case insensitive
3. Structure of XML in each row is different

I used below query to do that,

```
select * from TableName Where Cast(xmlcolumn as varchar(max) ) like '%searchString%'
```

this works for short length xml rows, if row length goes huge it cant handle the situation. Only partial of the data was searched.

Suggest me some other ways to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is one time task then I would use `exist` XML method thus:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CommentAsXML XML
)

INSERT  @Table1 (CommentAsXML)
VALUES  (N'<root><item /><item type="Reg">0001</item><item type="Inv">B007</item><item type="Cus">A0001</item><item type="Br">F0001</item></root>')
INSERT  @Table1 (CommentAsXML)
VALUES  (N'<root><item /><item type="Reg">0005</item><parent><child>B007</child></parent><item type="Br">F0005</item></root>')
INSERT  @Table1 (CommentAsXML)
VALUES  (N'<root><item /><item type="Reg">0005</item></root>')

-- Following query is searching for B007 within InnerText of all XML elements:
SELECT  *
FROM    @Table1 t
WHERE   t.CommentAsXML.exist('//*[lower-case(text()[1]) eq "b007"]') = 1
```

Results:

```
ID CommentAsXML
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  <root><item type="Reg">0001</item><item type="Inv">B007</item><item type="Cus">A0001</item><item type="Br">F0001</item></root>
2  <root><item type="Reg">0005</item><parent><child>B007</child></parent><item type="Br">F0005</item></root>
```

Also, if you want to search for some text in XML atrributes' values then following XQuery could be used:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @Table1 t
WHERE   t.CommentAsXML.exist('//@*[lower-case(.) eq "reg"]') = 1
```

Note: in both cases, string constants (ex. "reg") should be with lower cases.

Comment: Ya I have came across exist method. but it is case sensitive. Any way to search with case insensitive ?

Comment: @vignesh: See updated solution: you could use `lower-case` (or `upper-case`) XQuery function.